# Instagram api does not return data

Tags: python, api, instagram

The instagram api returs this when triying to get latest post by hashtag:

```
{"pagination":{"deprecation_warning":"next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"},"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

This is the url I use for the query:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/paris/media/recent?access_token=ACCESTOKENHERE
```

I tried using someone else access token and it works well. What is causing this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue. It seems that Instagram apps in "Sandbox Mode", i.e. those created after 17 November do not have access to `public_content`.

This is why using an access code of another app (presumably one that isn't in Sandbox mode) works.

Comment: Confirmed, after an entire morning of trying. A Sandbox app will get a Page not Found 404 instead of a JSON using the python-instagram client for something like `api.create_subscription(object='tag', object_id='fox', aspect='media', callback_url='http://example.com/mycallback')`. The sandbox for clients registered from now on is dead for most of use cases.

Answer (score 0):

For apps registered after Nov 17, 2015. A few endpoints return different data in Sandbox mode. The endpoint you are using is also one of them. Unless your app goes live, you can't fetch public content

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to the last 20 for each user.

Source: http://instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with PHP (language doesn't matter by the way). I saw on the [Sandbox page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/) these 3 conditions:

> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users
> - Reduced API rate limits

You can only get the data from sandbox users, whom you can invite via the Manage Clients section.

1. Visit [Manage Clients](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/).
2. Click **edit** for your app.
3. Go to the **Sandbox** tab.
4. Add some users to invite.
5. Get them to [accept the invitation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/sandbox_invites/) and auth ([make sure you have the scopes set up properly!](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/)).
6. Rejoice in the glory of their data.

Answer (score -1):

Use an `access_token` with permission `public_content`. Just direct the user to your `authorization URL` with `scopes`:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code&scope=basic+public_content
```

to get the permission.

Read more about [Login Permissions (Scopes)](http://instagram.com/developer/authorization/).

Comment: I had done that already and does not work, I think it is what Kyle Oliveiro says